# Firebase Storage in a Java Server

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage

Hello I just connect my java Server with Cloud Firestore of Firebase. I wonder if connecting my Java Server with Firebase Storage will be using the same method.

To connect with Cloud Firestore I carried out:

```
private BBDDEstablishment() {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
    FirebaseOptions options = null;

    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(PATH);
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL).build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (serviceAccount != null) {
                serviceAccount.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you execute your code?

Comment: [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) and [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) are different products in the Firebase platform. Which one are you trying to use in the code you shared? And what is the problem you get when you run that code? A good way to frame your problem is in the form of "When I ran this code I expected it to do ABC, but it did XYZ instead."

Comment: Hi Frank, this code refers to Cloud Firestore. It works perfectly. My question is if this code serves for Firebase Storage. If it not, I will appreciate a solution.